# Descent of coherent sheaves on finite coverings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, involutions

Let $X$ be a non-singular hyperelliptic curve (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $\pi:X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a $2:1$ covering. Let $\sigma:X \to X$ be the hyperelliptic involution and $E$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$ such that $
\sigma^* E \cong E$. Then, does there exist a locally free sheaf $F$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ such that $\pi^*F \cong E$?

Comment: No: Galois descent is not faithfully flat descent for generically Galois finite flat covers that are not etale. Choose $x \in X$ at which $\pi$ is ramified and let $z=\pi(x)$, so $\{x\}$ is $\sigma$-stable. The inverse ideal sheaf $E=O(x)$ is isomorphic to its own $\sigma$-pullback (even in a manner that restricts to a descent datum over $\mathbf{P}^1-\{z\}$, which you didn't ask to be satisfied but should have required).  This $E$ is not the pullback of a vector bundle $F$ on the base, as otherwise $F$ would be a line bundle and $1=\deg(E) = \deg(\pi)\deg(F)=2\deg(F)$ is even, an absurdity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\sigma^*E \cong E$. Then $E$ is a pullback if and only if the action of $\sigma$ on the fiber of $E$ at each ramification point of $\pi$ is trivial.

In the counterexample of nfdc23, the $\sigma$ acts by $-1$ on the fiber at $x$.

Comment: Don't you need to assume the isomorphism $f:\sigma^*(E)\simeq E$ satisfies $f\circ \sigma^*(f)= {\rm{id}}_E$ (so it is a descent datum away from the branch locus)?

Comment: @nfdc23: Of course you are right, the bundle should be equivariant.